# Can't Return Variable from Auth Form in C#

Tags: c#

I have two projects.  One is called Main and the other UserAuth.  I don't want to run Main unless the user passes UserAuth.  I know there is a lot wrong with my code and that's why I'm asking for help.  What I would like to do is to return userAuthenticated from this LoginForm.  I can't figure out how to do it.  I made a public variable userAuthenticated but I have no way of accessing it.  Here is my code:

```
namespace UserAuth
{
  public partial class LoginForm : Form
  {
    public bool userAuthenticated;

    private int attempts = 0;

    public bool LoginForm()   // Error  'LoginForm': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type    UserAuth    
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        return (userAuthenticated);
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // authenticate user -- works fine }
```

Called by:

```
    LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
    lf.Show();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The constructor is supposed to return a constructed instance of a class. If you make it return a `bool` then you'd be breaking the contract for a constructor.

Comment: Can you add the code that calls this LoginForm class?

Comment: @MatiasCicero - I know but I can't figure out a way around it!  It's a problem.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks - I just did.

Comment: Why are you trying to return a value from a constructor? A constructor should just be meant to "build" your object (hence: "constructor"). Do whatever you need to do with `userAuthenticated` somewhere else. On creation does not seem appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove all that global variable and I would work only with the predefined pattern expected by a modal dialog. In other words I would set the property DialogResult of your btnLogin to DialogResult.Cancel through the Winforms designer and then modify the code in the btnLogin_Click

```
// this is the form constructor, cannot return anything here
public LoginForm()   
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // this method contains your logic to authenticate the user
    // the method returns true if the user is ok or false if not
    bool result = AuthenticateUser();

    // If the user is authenticated close the login form setting OK
    // as the return value
    if(result)
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    // else the return from the form will be DialogResult.Cancel as 
    // set in the button's DialogResult property
}
```

Now the code that calls the login form should be simply

```
using(LoginForm fLogin = new LoginForm())
{
    if(DialogResult.OK == fLogin.ShowDialog())
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Login OK");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
    }
}
```